# PhpMyAdmin- Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I am trying to create a table using PHPMyAdmin. 
I need an enum field within the table. However, when I try to create it, after I've added the values along with the other fields, I get this:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`` ) NOT NULL , `category` ENUM('Fruit and Veg','Meat and Poultry','Bakery','Dairy ``' at line 1

My code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `supermarket_food`.`products` 
  ( `id` INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `prod_name` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    `brand` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , 
    `price` DOUBLE(4) NOT NULL , 
    `category` ENUM('Fruit and Veg','Meat and Poultry','Bakery','Dairy','Canned foods','Minerals','Biscuits and Candy','Savory Snacks','Beers, wines and Spirits') NOT NULL , 
    `expiry_date` DATE NOT NULL , 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I voted to close this because it has the same problem and the same solution as another past question: `DOUBLE` requires two arguments (or none). The error has nothing to do with ENUM, it's just coincidence that ENUM is the following column in your table and appears in the error message.

Comment: Though ENUM is not the issue in this particular case, and the ENUM example (I'm assuming) may be a prelude to some other future relational effort, you might also want to [see this info](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) about the use of the ENUM type.